# __proto__: Array(0) meaning in javascript- ionic firestore

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an application which has a search bar that connects to firebase and retrieves data and puts it in the search results

I know thanks to a console.log that the database is connecting to the application as can be seen in the array printed here in the console

```
2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {category: "u11", location: "glasgow"}
1: {category: "u13", location: "stirling"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

However, my search bar is not returning any results. I am guessing the error is down to the **proto** object. I have tried doing some research but to no avail. Does anyone know the meaning of this.

I will attach the html and homepage.ts file used to connect and create the search bar. Perhaps there is an error in there. 
My firestore collection is called competitions and I am trying to filter by location

Homepage.html

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Competition Search
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-searchbar
    showcancelbutton=""
    (ioninput)="filterList($event)"
  ></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of goalList">
      <ion-label>{{ item.competitionlocation }}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Homepage.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  public goalList: any[];
  public loadedGoalList: any[];
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firestore.collection(`competition`).valueChanges()
      .subscribe(goalList => {
        this.goalList = goalList;
        this.loadedGoalList = goalList;
        console.log(goalList);
    });
  }

  initializeItems(): void {
    this.goalList = this.loadedGoalList;
  }

  filterList(evt) {
    this.initializeItems();

    const searchTerm = evt.srcElement.value;

    if (!searchTerm) {
      return;
    }

    this.goalList = this.goalList.filter(currentGoal => {
      if (currentGoal.competitionlocation && searchTerm) {
        if (currentGoal.competitionlocation.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that log. It's just an ordinary array, displaying `Array.prototype` as its prototype.

Comment: Okay thanks i guess the issue is elsewhere